# mixed java and scala code, is it a good practice to use @BeanProperty?

Tags: java, scala

I have a mixed Java and Scala code.

In my Java code I usually access `DTO's` via their `dto.getSomething()`. Now that I'm starting to introduce new Scala code, I don't want some old Java code that uses old DTO's to use them as `getProperty()`.

If it would access a Scala `DTO` to look totally different meaning `ScalaDTO.property()` does that mean that for **readability** of my code I would need to add `@BeanProperty` to all of my Scala properties which would be used by Java code as well as used in Scala code?

Although this would resolve my readability problem, this would introduce clutter into my Scala code (@BeanProperty to all Scala code as they might get used in my Java code...)

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've generally used @BeanProperty only where Java style getters and setters are necessary for some legacy Java framework, eg Spring or Jersey. Aside from the clutter of the annotations themselves, you have the clutter of calling the getters and setters. Additionally, you'll need to use var properties instead of val, when case classes or other immutable data structures are the generally preferred Scala approach, especially for something like Dtos.

I think it's a personal stylistic preference, but as I prefer Scala both stylistically and for its practical benefits, eg immutability, I tend to try to push mixed code bases toward Scala idioms rather than Java idioms.